# xcopy in task scheduler ends with error 4

Tags: task-scheduler, xcopy

I created a task in task scheduler to copy a specific file to a server each midnight. When I run the command normally in command line it works fine, but the task always ends with exit code 4 and the file is not copied. Command I put to the command line is this:

`xcopy \\<server>.<domain>.com\c$\Users\a.Name.Surname\Documents\New_ADuser_mustang.ps1 C:\IAM\New_ADuser_mustang.ps1* /C /Y /Q`

In the task, I put to Action definition Action: Start a program, Program/script: `xcopy`, and to Add arguments (optional): `\\<server>.<domain>.com\c$\Users\a.Name.Surname\Documents\New_ADuser_mustang.ps1 C:\IAM\New_ADuser_mustang.ps1* /C /Y /Q`

xml code of the task is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.4" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2020-02-26T09:55:29.6760961</Date>
    <Author><domain>\<user></Author>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <CalendarTrigger>
      <StartBoundary>2020-02-27T00:00:00</StartBoundary>
      <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT1H</ExecutionTimeLimit>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <ScheduleByDay>
        <DaysInterval>1</DaysInterval>
      </ScheduleByDay>
    </CalendarTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>S-1-5-18</UserId>
      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>StopExisting</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>false</DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>
    <UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>false</UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT0S</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>xcopy</Command>
      <Arguments>\\<server>.<domain>.com\c$\Users\<user>\Documents\New_ADuser_mustang.ps1 C:\IAM\New_ADuser_mustang.ps1* /C /Y /Q</Arguments>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

Comment: 1) You copy single file - so `/C` option and asterisk at the end of destination file name are excess. 2) Have you specified the account the task is running from? Have you specified for environment loading? does the credentials for accessing remote file are stored? pay attention - you use admin share... can you alter it to some specific shared resource (or create it)?

Comment: I specified SYSTEM as the account to use with the task. What do you mean by environment loading? I'll put the task to the question as xml code.